# Error: unresolved reference recycler view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am doing a tutorial out of a book for the android studio (100% novice to kotlin and A studio), and I can't seem to get the code working for recycle view.

layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager

In my code (or the book's code, direct copy, and paste) "recyclerView" in the second line is red and the compiler says "unresolved reference recycler view". and I can't work out why?

the activity_main.xml has the id of the recycler view as just the default "RecyclerView", but when I try changing

```
recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
```

to

```
RecyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
```

that error message disappears but then the layout manager becomes an unresolved reference so that clearly does not work.

my code is as follows:

```
package com.example.quickquotes2022

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
 lateinit var layoutManager : LinearLayoutManager
 lateinit var adapter: QuoteAdapter

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    RecyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager

    adapter = QuoteAdapter()
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
}
}
```

Comment: You made an error in your code `recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager` @KotlinRookie

Comment: even when i set the code above i still get unresolved reference. (I was supposed to reset the capital R to a lower case r for this post but forgot to)

Comment: I have solved this now, Thankyou for the input. it turns out the id in the xml file was different i had to change it to android:id="@+id/recyclerView"